# During Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, I got the kernel related error: "could not get modinfo from 'crc32' as there was no such file or directory"

Tags: kernel

I'm running a Plesk server on AWS latest infrastructure (May, 2021) which I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, in accordance to the Plesk [guidance](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213410369-How-to-perform-dist-upgrade-procedure-on-Linux-server-with-Plesk-?source=search).

During this upgrade process I got the below error message:

```
could not get modinfo from 'crc32' as there was no such file or directory
```

[SSH Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyqc4.png)

I do have at the moment crc32 module installed:

```
# lsmod | grep crc
libcrc32c              16384  4 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,raid456

# dpkg -l | grep linux-modules | grep "ii  "
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-1047-aws           5.4.0-1047.49                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-1048-aws           5.4.0-1048.50                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-73-generic         5.4.0-73.82                                      amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-73-generic   5.4.0-73.82                                      amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

May I ask:

1. What was it that went wrong?
2. How can I diagnose the issue? and,
3. What should be done to fix it?

Comment: Also asked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339395/during-ubuntu-upgrade-from-18-to-20-i-got-the-kernel-related-error-could-not

Comment: Hi @guiverc, 

There are Ubuntu 18 (which is 18.04) and Ubuntu 20 (which is 20.04), as can be seen here:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213410369-How-to-perform-dist-upgrade-procedure-on-Linux-server-with-Plesk-?source=search

It's a bit strange as by "Also asked at" you were pointing to the URL of this exact same page. Possibly you were referring to the Post system:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462391

As I considered this as being legitimate and pluralism of ideas, may I ask if this is consider less acceptable over here?

Comment: No Ubuntu has had products that use *yy* format, they are *snap* only products such as Ubuntu Core 18 so Ubuntu 18 implies a *snap* only release where `dpkg` and `apt` are invalid commands (*deb* packaged systems use the *yy.mm* format). It's been that way since 2016.  The *snap* only systems are smaller which is a plus for devices/appliances, and cloud use (faster to spin up & need less resources), plus have 10 years of supported life (double that of LTS releases, though less if ESM is included).  Sorry I'll meant to use https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462391

Comment: Canonical is the company behind Ubuntu; the Ubuntu community likewise know what the releases are; just because a 3rd party site (support.plesk.com) says something incorrect - it's not fact (it's a warning they don't know the product very well as they're mixing up two different products!) thus I'd use that as a sign to be careful of their advice.. Everyone makes mistakes, but in a careless guide like that shows sloppiness.   FYI:  If you upgrade Ubuntu Core 18 to Ubuntu Core 20; no apps need changing as *snaps* are the same all releases! (recall they don't use *deb* packages!)

Comment: I got this message also after running `apt-get upgrade`. Following the link and the advice at the other page I ran ` sudo update-initramfs -u`, which completed quickly, but I don't know if it tackled the issue (or even what it did at all).